# Symfony/Propel: i18n tables

Tags: internationalization, symfony1, propel

i have this schema and fixtures:

```
  sedi:
    _attributes:  { isI18N: true, i18nTable: sediI18n }
    id:           ~


  sediI18n:
    id:  { type: integer, required: true, primaryKey: true, foreignTable: sedi, foreignReference: id }
    culture: { isCulture: true, type: varchar, size: 7, required: true, primaryKey: true }
    paese_indirizzo:  { type: varchar(6), required: true }
    indirizzo:        { type: varchar(1024), required: true }


Sedi:
  sede_roma_1:             { }


SediI18n:
  sede_roma_1_italiano:             { id: sede_roma_1, culture: it, paese_indirizzo: eu, indirizzo: "Ufficio di Roma 1 Testaccio Via Galvani, 17 Roma - 00153 Italia" }
  sede_roma_1_francese:             { id: sede_roma_1, culture: fr, paese_indirizzo: eu, indirizzo: "Rome Office 1: Testaccio Via Galvani, 17 Roma - 00153 Italia" }
```

I'm trying to show in a template only the sede in Italian language ("Ufficio di Roma") but it shows also the sede in French language..

In that template I have write `var_dump($sf_user->getCulture())` and prints "it".

Any idea?

Comment: Could you also include the PHP code you use to select and display the values?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you stay with the conventions and use lowercase characters and underscores for the table names. In fact, you don't have to write much code to get I18N support. What should be enough:

```
sedi:
  id:

sedi_i18n:
  paese_indirizzo: { type: varchar(6), required: true }
  indirizzo: { type: varchar(1024), required: true }
```

Adapt your fixtures accordingly.